# Finalize filter for Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, filter, slider, swiper.js

Help to finalize the filter for swiper js. It is necessary that when filtering, the length of the slider changes so that there is no empty space where the slides were. It is also necessary that the lower slides (.myswiper) are also filtered out. Thank you!

```
`https://codepen.io/vovp63488/pen/VwxOwrj`
```